# Error report - ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql

Getting error of "missing right parenthesis"

```
CREATE TABLE university(
    name VARCHAR2(150) NOT NULL,
    id INT(50) NOT NULL,
    code VARCHA(80) NOT NULL UNIQUE KEY,
    established year DATE ,
    PRIMARY KEY(name)
);
```

Comment: Maybe related to the apparent typo: "VARCHA" instead of "VARCHAR" or "VARCHAR2".

Answer (score 1):

I think there are a couple of syntax items:

- As showdev mentioned, you need 'VARCHAR2' for the 'code' column
- 'established year' had a space in it (so i've put an underscore)
- i've put your unique constraint and primary key into the correct syntax as per what I can see in the oracle spec (your way may work, but I am not familiar with the exact syntax).

  ```
  CREATE TABLE university(
      name VARCHAR2(150) NOT NULL,
      id INT NOT NULL,
      code VARCHAR2(80) NOT NULL,
      established_year DATE ,
      CONSTRAINT name_pk PRIMARY KEY(name),
      CONSTRAINT code_unique UNIQUE (code)
  );
  ```

Comment: . . You can usually test such code online:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=eb42e2a7ce3d6563265fdd54bda5daf3.